# avoid for/else in this prime numbers generator function, use pure for loop

Tags: python, primes

I am doing an exercise about generator to generate prime numbers.

Even though I've got a solution about this problem. I wonder if I don't know or want to use for/else loop. How can I make it  with only for loop.

```py
def genPrimes(): 
    primes = [] # primes generated so far 
    last = 1 # last number tried 
    while True: 
        last += 1 
        for p in primes: 
            if last % p == 0: 
                break 
        else: 
            primes.append(last) 
            yield last
```

Comment: You could set a flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive functions if you want to :

```
def prime_number(n, d):
    if n//2 < d:
      return True
    if n%d == 0:
      return False
    return prime_number(n, d+1)

def find_primes(n,i, result):
  if i == n + 1:
    return result
  if prime_number(i, 2):
    result.append(i)
  return find_primes(n, i+1, result)

print(find_primes(100,2, []))
```

Using loops is better here because its simpler and avoids stack overflow ;)